# Since upgrading to Robolectric 4.3, a ListView's onItemClickListener is getting a null View

Tags: android, robolectric

The layout of my activity is basically this (simplified to illustrate the problem). Basically there's not much space for the `ListView` to appear if the device has a small screen, because other views take up all the space:

```xml
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
    <SomeBigView
        layout_width="match_parent"
        layout_height="680dp"/>
    <ListView
        layout_width="match_parent"
        layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My activity code sets up the item click listener as follows:

```
list.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, view, _, _ ->
    Snackbar.make(view, "Clicked on $view", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

My unit test taps on the first item in the list:

```
val controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
    .create().start().resume().visible()
val list: ListView = controller.get().findViewById(R.id.list)
shadowOf(list).performItemClick(0)
```

With Robolectric 4.2.1, my click listener is called with a non-null `view`.
With Robolectric 4.3, it's called with a `null` view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary**: 
The solution is to specify a larger device height for this test with the `@Config(qualifiers="h780dp")` annotation.

**Details**:
After some debugging, I discovered that with Robolectric 4.2.1, the height of the `ListView` was `146` (`top=680`, `bottom=826`), but with Robolectric 4.3 it's `0` (`top=680`, `bottom=680`). The default device height used by Robolectric is `470`, which isn't enough to display the list. The list doesn't have any child views with Robolectric 4.3.

The implementation of `shadowOf(list).performItemClick(0)` is found in `ShadowAdapterView` from robolectric, and is:

```java
public boolean performItemClick(int position) {
    return realAdapterView.performItemClick(realAdapterView.getChildAt(position),
        position, realAdapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(position));
}
```

With Robolectric 4.3, `getChildAt(position)` returns `null`, which is what is forwarded to the click listener.

The workaround is to specify a larger device screen for this test. For example:

```
@Test
@Config(qualifiers="h780dp")
```

Comment: Depending on the case, you may also want to verify how this activity looks like on an actual small device.